# 「MySQL サーバにログインできません」と表示されたのに、「MySQLサーバーは正常に稼働している」と表示されるのはなぜ？

Tags: mysql

DB使用しているサイトが表示されなくなり、確認してみたら「MySQL サーバにログインできません」と表示されました。

下記コマンドを打ったら、「MySQLサーバーは正常に稼働している」と表示されたように見えました。

```
$ sudo systemctl status mysqld
● mysqld.service - MySQL Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mysqld.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since 金 2024-02-02 14:42:18 JST; 1 weeks 1 days ago
     Docs: man:mysqld(8)
           http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/en/using-systemd.html
  Process: 20019 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld --daemonize --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid $MYSQLD_OPTS (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 19995 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/mysqld_pre_systemd (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 20022 (mysqld)
   CGroup: /system.slice/mysqld.service
           └─20022 /usr/sbin/mysqld --daemonize --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid

Warning: Journal has been rotated since unit was started. Log output is incomplete or unavailable.
```

再起動コマンドを打ったら、サイトが表示されMySQL サーバにもログインできるようになりました。

```
$ sudo systemctl restart mysqld
```

環境
CentOS7
ＭySQL5.7

Q1.「MySQL サーバにログインできません」と表示されたのに、「MySQLサーバーは正常に稼働している」と表示されたように見えたのはなぜですか？

Q2.次に同じような状況になったときは、何を確認すればよいですか？
・「MySQL サーバにログインできません」と表示された時に、その状態の詳細を確認したい。可能ならそうなった理由を知りたい。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

「MySQL サーバにログインできません」がどのようなアプリケーションでどのように表示されているのかがわからないため正確に言えませんが、一般的にMySQLサーバーにログインできない原因は次のものが考えられます。

- MySQLサーバーが正常に動作していない。

  - MySQLサーバーがそもそも起動していない。
  - ポートまたはUNIXドメインソケットをリッスンしていない。
  - ハングアップやバグ等で正常な通信ができない状態になっている。
- MySQLサーバーへアクセスできない。

  - 接続しようとしているホスト名(IPアドレス)とポート、または、UNIXドメインソケットのパスが間違っている。
  - SELinux等の機能によりネットワークやUNIXドメインソケットへのアクセスが制限されている。
  - ファイアウォール等で通信が遮断されている。
- MySQLサーバーとの通信が確立できない。

  - クライアントとサーバーが対応しているプロトコルに互換性がない。
  - SSL/TLS等の暗号化について対応できる組合せがない。
  - 対応している認証の組合せがない。
- MySQLサーバーへアクセスするときのログイン情報が間違っている。

  - ユーザー名が間違っている。
  - パスワードが間違っている。
  - 接続しようとしているユーザー名@接続ホスト(IPアドレス)のユーザーが存在しない。
  - 接続しようとしているデータベースへのアクセス権がない。

`systemctl status mysqld`で確認できることは一番最初の「MySQLサーバーがそもそも起動していない。」を確認できるかどうか程度です。それ以外は`systemctl status mysqld`で確認する事はできません。`systemctl status mysqld`で正常に起動しているとなっていても、「MySQL サーバにログインできません」と表示される可能性があります。

では、「MySQL サーバにログインできません」がどうして表示されたのか、上記のどれにあたるのかは、その表示しているアプリケーションが上記のどのエラーに対してその表示をするようにできているのかによるため、そのアプリケーションが何なのかわからないとわかりません。

Comment: 「MySQL サーバにログインできません」は、phpMyAdminで表示されました。因果関係は不明ですが、ディスク容量が 100 %になっていたので、それを解消したことがもしかしたらログインできるようになったことに関係しているかもしれません。

Answer (score 1):

`systemctl status` の結果で分かるのはあくまで「プロセスが動いている」であり、これだけで「正常に動いている」と判断するのは早計です (実際問題があったわけですから)

より詳細を確認するにはログファイルの中身を見てください。
MySQL のログなら `/var/log/mysql/` 配下、もしくは OS 全般の状況を確認するには `/var/log/messages` も一緒に確認する必要があるでしょう。